# box-shadow only working in Chrome when disabled and re-enabled through dev tools

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've been playing around with [Cute File Browser](https://tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php) and having an issue with the thumbnails of files displaying in Chrome. The issue is also present on their [demo page](https://demo.tutorialzine.com/2014/09/cute-file-browser-jquery-ajax-php/).

When the page initially loads, the thumbnail for the file looks like this:

[image]

When I go through dev tools (right-click and inspect the thumbnail), if I disable the box-shadow CSS rule, and then re-enable it, the thumbnail then displays correctly:

[image: _image_]

The CSS in question is:

```css
box-shadow: 1.74em -2.1em 0 0 #a94bb7 inset;
```

which is applied to the `<span class="icon file f-html">.html</span>` element.

Loading the page in Firefox works with no issues. Why does Chrome behave in this way, and what can I do to make it display correctly without the rule needing to be disabled/re-enabled?

Comment: Looks like something worth [filing a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) for. I've run into these issues in the past, it's never fun to debug (throwing all you can at it like `transform:translateZ(0);` for example).

Comment: @chriskirknielsen it may be the way to go with it unfortunately, I've been trying various things for a couple hours with no joy. I was secretly hoping I was being an idiot and had missed something obvious!